# Facebook Comment Box issue with firefox

Tags: firefox, comments, facebook-comments

I am facing an issue with firefox, my fb comment box is displaying on chrome and safari except firefox.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="xxxxxx" data-num-posts="10" data-width="500"></div>
</b:if>
```

this is html opening tag

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```